# select2 - color tag based on selection order

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

I have a drop down select input (built using the select2 plugin), and **my goal is that each of the selected tags take on a color**, in order to help readability. For instance, **the first *selected* tag would be blue, the second would be red etc**.

I don't manage to do it, for at least two reasons:

- how to access (DOM manipulation) the selected tags? I can access children of the select elmt and check whether they are selected (using the `data-select2-id` ? How does this one work btw, I can't explain myself the values it takes in the example below), but since I have **10000+ possibilities** and expect 2 **or 3 selections** this seems like a sub-optimal approach.
- how to specify their color?

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45946496/changing-the-background-color-of-a-select2-selection-within-the-select-field), how to change the background color of my input, but that is not at all what I am trying to do.

In fact I need the tag to take on a particular color so that the user can map it to it corresponding coloured entry in a chart.

Can you tell me how to fix this minimal example ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slm15/2nqsr4nL/1/)) to have this please?

A [similar question exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822933/styling-individual-select2-tags) but it has not been answered, and it has no minimal example.

ADD:
According to [that thread](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/text-color-in-a-select-box/1218/3), a solution could be to give a color to each of the possible options as in the following. But since I have a large number of possible options, this does not really do..

```
option.line1 {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
}

option.line2 {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffff00;
}


<option class="line1" value="menu1">Menu Item 1</option>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest to use [selection templating](https://select2.org/selections#templating), so you can customize the appearance of selected results by using the `templateSelection` configuration option.

In your case you can operate on `container` parameter of `templateSelection` function like below:

```
templateSelection: function (data, container) {
    $(container).css("background-color", colors[data.id]);
    return data.text;
}
```

Here is a complete snippet coloring selected tags based on their `id`:

```js
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "orange", "yellow"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var checkList = [1, 3];
  $("#myList").select2({
   width: "100%",
    templateSelection: function (data, container) {
      $(container).css("background-color", colors[data.id]);
      return data.text;
    },
  }).val(checkList).trigger("change");
})
```

```css
.select2-selection__choice {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <select multiple="multiple" id="myList">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
    <option value="3">Orange</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Or your fiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/n9todvv8/

---

#### Update:

Below is a complete snippet coloring selected tags based on their **position in selection**.

In the code below the `select2:select` event handler prevents the Select2 plugin sorting the selection, so that tags appear in the order in which they were selected:

```js
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "orange", "yellow"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var checkList = [1, 3];
  $("#myList").select2({
   width: "100%",
    templateSelection: function (data, container) {
      var selection = $('#myList').select2('data');
      var idx = selection.indexOf(data);
      console.log(">>Selection",data.text, data.idx, idx);
      data.idx = idx;
      
      $(container).css("background-color", colors[data.idx]);
      return data.text;
    },
  }).val(checkList).trigger("change");

  
  $("#myList").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
    var element = evt.params.data.element;
    var $element = $(element);

    $element.detach();
    $(this).append($element);
    $(this).trigger("change");
  });
  
})
```

```css
.select2-selection__choice {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <select multiple="multiple" id="myList">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Mango</option>
    <option value="3">Orange</option>
    <option value="4">Banana</option>
    <option value="5">Kiwi</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

New fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/phabypbt/

---

Reference:

- [Select2 issue: In multi-select, selections do not appear in the order in which they were selected](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3106)
- [Select2: How to prevent tags sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431197/select2-how-to-prevent-tags-sorting)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The output is very much like what I am after except that with this solution, the color given to the tags depend on their `id` attribute, rather than on their position in the select bar. Indeed I would like "the first selected tag [to] be (for instance) blue, the second [to] be red etc." Otherwise, with 10'000+ tags, I risk having the same color for different tags very often, which can confuse the user. Is there a way to achieve this please? I looked for an attribute that tells me the position of the option within the `select` container but could not find one.

Comment: But the selected tags are presented sorted according to the option list order, so the position substantially corresponds to this order (and so its `id`)

Answer (score 1):

This can be a solution or can be a point of start for you, please take a look, here i'm getting all choices selected, and using a loop i'm setting colors to it using the select2 id:

```
    var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "cyan", "orange", "aliceblue", "purple"]; 
    //random colors that i created

    var selections = $(".select2-selection__choice");
    //this above will return all selections

    if (selections.length){
       for (var i = 0; i < selections.length; i++){
            var selection = selections[i];
            var selectionJQ = $(selection);
            var select2ID = selectionJQ[0].dataset.select2Id;   //here you can get some infos from select2  
            colorName   = colors[select2ID];

            selectionJQ.attr("style", "background: " + colorName + " !important");
        }
    }
```

Here's a fiddle to see if is that what you need: https://jsfiddle.net/nw0rd0dk/

**EDIT**
To help with the questions you posted in the comments, I created a new fiddle.
 https://jsfiddle.net/bdotckdu/ 
1) the simpler way I found is to encapsulate every select with a div, then find just the child choices from the select that is inside the single div (the fiddle will help to understand)
2) It works, you had an error in the fiddle that was causing it to not work, i fixed it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. The output looks v. much like what I was after. 2 questions. First, isn't using `.select2-selection__choice` an issue if you have several `select` inputs on the page? Second, how comes the code does not work if I nest it inside a `.change()` bloc (https://jsfiddle.net/slm15/2nqsr4nL/2/)? Thanks.